# Scroll a div with overflow hidden to center a element inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with several elements inside it. Each one of them works as a pagination number and, when I click one of them, the container div must scroll to center this element.

The div has an overflow: hidden behavior so I must find the actual size of the div, not only the visible part of it.

Answer (score 7):

First you need to find the **inside width of the div**.
You can use for it:

```
$("#divOverflowHidden")[0].scrollWidth
```

Now you need to calculate the **position of the element** that must be *something like this*:

```
{element index} * {overflow hidden div inside width} / {number of elements}
```

*The code should be something like this:*

```
 index * $("#divOverflowHidden")[0].scrollWidth / total
```

Now you need to **move the scroll bar** to the right position using `$("#divOverflowHidden").scrollLeft()` if you have a horizontal scroll bar or `$("#divOverflowHidden").scrollTop()` if you have a vertical scroll bar.

The result is that the element will be shown in the left of the overflowed div. To centralize the element, you could subtract the result of the calculation, a half of the external width of the overflowed div. So the new formula is:

```
(({element index} * {overflow hidden div inside width}) / {number of elements}) - ({overflow hidden div ouside width} / 2)
```

Finaly...

```
((index * $("#divOverflowHidden")[0].scrollWidth) / total) - $("#divOverflowHidden").width() / 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **scrollHeight**, in javascript:

```
document.getElementById("container").scrollHeight;
```

or jQuery

```
$("#container")[0].scrollHeight;
```

example here: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/szxrfx3m/6/)